# Find out who logged in as me, using su

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On linux one can (if he has sudo rights) log in, and take control of another users account/username, doing `sudo su - username`

But is there a way to find out who logged in like this, and used my account?

Comment: Should be more on topic on SuperUser or Unix&Linux, but sudo can be configured for extensive logs (any sudo-ed command). But anyway trying to protect your account from some one that has admin priviledges on the machine is close to non sense. You can only protect sensitive data at rest with cryptography. But the rule is: is you do not trust a machine's admin, do not use the machine.

Comment: Only idea what I got is to use `ps -u <username>` and manually find processes from not your terminal
Or if you just want to know if there is someone other logged as you, can use `netstat` (`nestat -a -p`) should works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `last` command .

`man last` :

> last, lastb - show a listing of last logged in users

```
DESCRIPTION

       last  searches  back through the /var/log/wtmp file (or the file desig‐
       nated by the -f option) and displays a list of all users logged in (and
       out)  since  that  file was created.  One or more usernames and/or ttys
       can be given, in which case last will show only  the  entries  matching
       those  arguments.  Names of ttys can be abbreviated, thus last 0 is the
       same as last tty0.
```

Answer (score 1):

`/var/log/auth.log` contains the  logging information for sudo attempts in ubuntu

Comment: It doesn't show what I asking, but I'll have to do with this. Thanks